# How to animate the backgroundColor of a ScrollView in React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to animate the backgroundColor of a ScrollView, but always get a warning - and a non-animating ScrollView.
Am I hitting a bug? Or is it simply not supported on a ScrollView? (It does work on a regular View.) 
I'm testing using Expo on an iOS iPhone.

Relevant code snippets:

```
<Animated.ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={[
    styles.container,
    this.getCurrentColorOfBackground()
  ]}>
  <Text onPress={this.onPress} style={styles.question}>
    {this.state.question}
  </Text>
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

the getCurrentColorOfBackground() method:

```
  getCurrentColorOfBackground = () => ({
    backgroundColor: this.backgroundColor.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ["#00aaFF", "#808080"]
    })
  });
```

the animation itself:

```
this.backgroundColor = new Animated.Value(0);
Animated.timing(this.backgroundColor, {
  toValue: 100,
  duration: 1000 * 60
}).start();
```

The warning message:

> 20:17:58: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `backgroundColor`
>   supplied to `ScrollView`: [object Object] Valid color formats are
>     - '#f0f' (#rgb)
>     - '#f0fc' (#rgba)
>     - '#ff00ff' (#rrggbb)
>     - '#ff00ff00' (#rrggbbaa)
>     - 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
>     - 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0)'
>     - 'hsl(360, 100%, 100%)'
>     - 'hsla(360, 100%, 100%, 1.0)'
>     - 'transparent'
>     - 'red'
>     - 0xff00ff00 (0xrrggbbaa)
>
> Bad object: {   "flexGrow": 1,   "alignItems": "center",
>   "justifyContent": "center",   "backgroundColor": "rgba(0, 170, 255,
>   1)" }
>       in ScrollView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)

In case you want to try it out yourself, the full component (and repo) is here: https://github.com/wim82/chapter-interview/blob/master/QuestionRotator.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply the backgroundColor inside the style property instead of contentContainerStyle of scrollView.

The Animated.Value(0) should be stored in the state, not as a class object (from the official docs and best practice).

I have modified your above code to make it work,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {


  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    // Intialize to default value
    this.state = {
      backgroundColor: new Animated.Value(0)
    };
  }

  onPress = () => {
    // onPress, initialize to default value using setState and start animation
    // after the state has been updated
    this.setState({ backgroundColor: new Animated.Value(0) }, () => {
       Animated.timing(this.state.backgroundColor, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 5000
      }).start();
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.ScrollView
        style={[
            styles.container,
            // Interpolation mapping from numbers to strings (colors)
            {
              backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 100],
                outputRange: ["#00aaFF", "#808080"]
              })
            }
          ]}
      >
        <Text
          // onPress to start Animation
          onPress={() => this.onPress() }
          style={styles.paragraph}
        >
          Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone!
          Save to get a shareable url.
        </Text>
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#34495e',
  },
});
```

Working snack example: https://snack.expo.io/BymzMdtRG

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Ravi! Though I noticed, the lack of setState was not necessarily the culprit, the problem was that i applied the styling to `contentContainerStyle` property of the ScrollView, while it should have been the regular `style` attribute. It works for my use case, but it means i can't animate the contentContainer view - which is different from the regular ScrollView. If you could reflect in your answer that i should have applied this to "style", i'll gladly accept it as the correct one. Many thanks!

Comment: I knew the problem could also be due to contentContainerStyle, but to make sure it's 100% working I added setState. But I forgot to add the style part in the answer. Good, you found it. Now I will add.

Comment: This might work for background color, but it definitely won't work for all styles. The `style` and `contentContainerStyle` props are applied to different views. For example, I need to animate the `transform, translateY` property of `contentContainerStyle` and simply applying the style animation to `style` instead does not yield the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate any properties of `contentContainerStyle` of a scrollview because the underlying component, `ScrollContentContainerViewClass`, is hardcoded by react-native and can't be changed. See the source code here:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/bbb6a0754ce4173e24d3c0b46a5350ff2a8690d3/Libraries/Components/ScrollView/ScrollView.js#L790-L802

You would need to open an issue and then submit a pull request adding a property to scrollView that would allow you to set `ScrollContentContainerViewClass`.