# React native - "this.setState is not a function" trying to animate background color?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

Alright Im just trying to loop the background color of a view, fading between 3-4 colors. I found [How to animate the backgroundColor of a ScrollView in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356933/how-to-animate-the-backgroundcolor-of-a-scrollview-in-react-native) and have copied verbatim, but looking at the Snack, I believe this answer is out of date.

With the following, I get the error:

> this.setState is not a function

```
export default props => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
        'SequelSans-RomanDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-RomanDisp.ttf'),
        'SequelSans-BoldDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-BoldDisp.ttf'),
        'SequelSans-BlackDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-BlackDisp.ttf'),
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {

      //Set states
      this.state = {
        backgroundColor: new Animated.Value(0)
      };
      this.setState({ backgroundColor: new Animated.Value(0) }, () => {
       Animated.timing(this.state.backgroundColor, {
        toValue: 100,
        duration: 5000
      }).start();
    });

        var color = this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 300],
            outputRange: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)']
        });

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: { flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 100],
                outputRange: ["#00aaFF", "#808080"]
              })
    },
```

Then I reference this style here:

```
return (
        <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.myText}>Login</Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      );
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE: - Rendered more hooks than during the previous render**

```
    export default props => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
        'SequelSans-RomanDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-RomanDisp.ttf'),
        'SequelSans-BoldDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-BoldDisp.ttf'),
        'SequelSans-BlackDisp' : require('./assets/fonts/SequelSans-BlackDisp.ttf'),
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {

    //Set states
      const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

      useEffect(() => {
        setBackgroundColor(new Animated.Value(0));
      }, []);    // this will be only called on initial mounting of component,
      // so you can change this as your requirement maybe move this in a function which will be called,
      // you can't directly call setState/useState in render otherwise it will go in a infinite loop.
      useEffect(() => {
        Animated.timing(this.state.backgroundColor, {
          toValue: 100,
          duration: 5000
        }).start();
      }, [backgroundColor]);

      var color = this.state.colorValue.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 300],
        outputRange: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)']
      });

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: { flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: color
    },
      textWrapper: {
        height: hp('70%'), // 70% of height device screen
        width: wp('80%'),   // 80% of width device screen
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      myText: {
        fontSize: hp('2%'), // End result looks like the provided UI mockup
        fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BoldDisp'
      }
    });

      return (
        <Animated.View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.myText}>Login</Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>
      );
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you try to use `const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(...)`

Comment: `this.state` and `this.setState` is used in Class Component, in your functional component you have to use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#state-hook) in hooks to control the state and setState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use this inside a functional component. The only mistake you made is you are trying to set state using **this.setState** inside a functional component instead of using **useState** hook which does the same work for functional component.

Just change your setState functionality using **useState** and **useEffect** hook as below:-

```
//Set states
const [backgroundColor, setBackgroundColor] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
const [colorValue, setColorValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0)); 

useEffect(() => {
  setBackgroundColor(new Animated.Value(0));
}, []);    // this will be only called on initial mounting of component, 
// so you can change this as your requirement maybe move this in a function which will be called, 
// you can't directly call setState/useState in render otherwise it will go in a infinite loop.
useEffect(() => {
  Animated.timing(backgroundColor, {
    toValue: 100,
    duration: 5000
  }).start();
}, [backgroundColor]);

var color = colorValue.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 300],
  outputRange: ['rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)']
});
```

This is how it could be done in a class component using **useState and useEffect** hooks, Enjoy!

Comment: Ok, I've updated my question with what I have currently - Im getting the error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render"

Comment: It would be hard to check with what you updated in your question. I would at least need to see the code of your complete component why it is being called multiple times and how are you calling it?

Comment: Check my question now - ive posted my whole component

Comment: Alright, came back to this - now having a problem with the this.state.colorValue part

Comment: @skyguy As I already mentioned on the first line of my answer we can't use this inside a functional component. You have to use useState if you want to store any variable inside functional component state. I didn't notice that we were using this.state for colorValue as well so now after your comment I have updated my answer please check.

Comment: I get 'colorValue.interpolate' is not a function

Comment: Yes because colorValue was not initialized as a animated value. I have updated my answer to help you fix this but the original context of the question is different and if you face any further issues which are not related to using this.setState then please raise a different question as solution to your question is already there :)